# Can't save files in my LARAVEL API folder with POSTMAN

Tags: php, laravel, api, file-upload, postman

I have a small problem when I try to upload an image from POSTMAN to my LARAVEL API, I am creating the path and name well, but when making the POST request the image is not saved in the supposed folder where it should be saved.

The route is for the creation of a product, and the image corresponds to it:

Route:

```
Route::post('product/new','ProductController@store');
```

In my controller:

```
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $request->input('name');
    //Other staff

    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = $product->name . '.' . $extension;
    $path = $file->move(public_path("/uploads/image/products/"), $filename);
    $product->image = $path;
```

And the POSTMAN config:

[image]

Already try to configure the Content type headers with: `x-www-form-urlencoded`, with Content type `multipart/form-data` and without `any Content type`, and none of the 3 worked

The result I'm getting is:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "test1",
//staff
"image": "/app/public/uploads/image/products/test1.png",
}
```

But if I check there:`/app/public/uploads/image/products/`  there are no saved images

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: post your `error_log` notices, warnings, and errors for the request

Comment: Also, what on earth are you doing placing uploads in the public folder? That's really insecure

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not having any error when making the request, it is supposed to store the image well, I only have one warning in the postman field when uploading the image, which is: "This file resides outside the working directory. Collaborators might not have the same file path. "
On the other hand, this API is going to be consumed from a front end that they are developing alternately, with that in mind, where should I save the images following the best practices and how the front end its going to get it?

Comment: Btw, I just realized that the public_path in my function takes it to app / public ... but in my laravel project I have the public folder in my root folder, and not in app /

Comment: storage all the way to save any files

Comment: unless you modified public path, 
default public_path of laravel won't bring you to "/app/public/uploads/image/products/test1.png"

Comment: I did not modified it, but with my function as it, it supose to brings the image there